# Table within Table within Table Loses Table Body Formatting

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I had a table that was working fine but then requirements were added.  The 
  table header should not move when the table is scrolled.  The scroll bar 
 should be in the table not using the browser scroll.  I tried a number of 
 things it did one without achieving the other I don't want the scroll to be 
 on the header.  It should be under the the table header.  I achieved this.
 To do it I had to add table with in a table withing a table.  I have 
 achieved most of my goal but the formatting is off for some reason I have 
 tried a number of things with ho luck.

The table is working but the formatting  is off.  The table header and 
  table body do not align in the table cells.  I tried trying to change the 
  width of header or the cells with no luck.  I have tried everything I can 
  think off I will give a image of the before and after.

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
 <div class="container">
   <div class="tableFixHead"> 
     <table class ="table pos-table" style="height: 400px;
       overflow-y:auto" cellpadding="0" cellmargin="0" 
        *ngIf='use && users.length'>

  <table class="table" style=" width:100%; position:sticky;                 
      margin-bottom:0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>Name</th>
           <th>Username</th>
           <th>Last Login</th>
           <th>Job Title</th>
           <th></th>
           </tr>
           </thead>
           </table>

<div class="scroll">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <tbody>               
            <tr *ngFor= 'let user of users'>
                <td>{{user.name}}</td>
                    <td headers="2">{{user.username}}</td>
                      <td>{{user.lastlogin | date: 'dd/MMM/yyyy  hh:mm 
                         UTC'}} 
                        </td>
                           <td>{{user.jobtitle}}</td>
                               <td style="float:right; color:#3C006E" 
                                   aria-hidden="true"><i 
                                     class="fa fa-envelope" title="Edit 
                                       email notification" 
                                        style="margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px; 
                                        color:#3C006E" arial                      
                                           hidden="true"> </i>
                                               <i class="fa fa-clone 
                                                   email-icon"  
                                                     style="margin-right: 
                                                          -15px; 
                                                           color:purple;" 

                                                         title="Clone 
                                                             this user                                        
                                                             aria- 
                                                    hidden="true"></i> 
        </td>
           </tr>
               </tbody>
                 </table>
                     </div>
                         </table>     
                             </div>
                                 </div>
                                    </div>

.pos-table{
    font-family:'Open Sans'; 
    font-size:13px;
    margin-left: 80px; 
    height:300px;
    overflow-y:auto;
      }



::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 3px;
    margin-right: -10px;
    }


scroll {
    height: 200px;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    overflow-y: scroll;
 }
```

The table header should be aligned with the table body.
   The table header and table body are not aligned

Comment: Please check this link: https://medium.com/@vembarrajan/html-css-tricks-scroll-able-table-body-tbody-d23182ae0fbc

Another example: https://codepen.io/nirmalkc/pen/oswdB

Answer (score 0):

you contain both of the child tables in a container table, but you don't have tr and td for this.
here:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
 <div class="container">
   <div class="tableFixHead"> 
     <table class ="table pos-table" style="height: 400px;
       overflow-y:auto" cellpadding="0" cellmargin="0" 
        *ngIf='use && users.length'>
    <tr><td>
              <table class="table" style=" width:100%; position:sticky;                 
                  margin-bottom:0 ;border:1px solid red">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                       <th>Name</th>
                       <th>Username</th>
                       <th>Last Login</th>
                       <th>Job Title</th>
                       <th></th>
                       </tr>
                       </thead>
                       </table>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<div class="scroll">
    <table class="table table-hover" colspan=2 style='border:1px solid black'>
        <tbody>               
            <tr *ngFor= 'let user of users'>
                <td>{{user.name}}</td>
                    <td >{{user.username}}</td>
                      <td>{{user.lastlogin | date: 'dd/MMM/yyyy  hh:mm 
                         UTC'}} 
                        </td>
                           <td>{{user.jobtitle}}</td>
                               <td style="float:right; color:#3C006E" 
                                   aria-hidden="true"><i 
                                     class="fa fa-envelope" title="Edit 
                                       email notification" 
                                        style="margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px; 
                                        color:#3C006E" arial                      
                                           hidden="true"> </i>
                                               <i class="fa fa-clone 
                                                   email-icon"  
                                                     style="margin-right: 
                                                          -15px; 
                                                           color:purple;" 

                                                         title="Clone 
                                                             this user                                        
                                                             aria- 
                                                    hidden="true"></i> 
        </td>
           </tr>
            <tr *ngFor= 'let user of users'>
                <td>{{user.name}}</td>
                    <td headers="2">{{user.username}}</td>
                      <td>{{user.lastlogin | date: 'dd/MMM/yyyy  hh:mm 
                         UTC'}} 
                        </td>
                           <td>{{user.jobtitle}}</td>
                               <td style="float:right; color:#3C006E" 
                                   aria-hidden="true"><i 
                                     class="fa fa-envelope" title="Edit 
                                       email notification" 
                                        style="margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px; 
                                        color:#3C006E" arial                      
                                           hidden="true"> </i>
                                               <i class="fa fa-clone 
                                                   email-icon"  
                                                     style="margin-right: 
                                                          -15px; 
                                                           color:purple;" 

                                                         title="Clone 
                                                             this user                                        
                                                             aria- 
                                                    hidden="true"></i> 
        </td>
           </tr>
               </tbody>
                 </table>
                     </div>
                     </td></tr>
                         </table>     
                             </div>
                                 </div>
                                    </div>
```

Comment: I appreciate your attempt to answer my question but I tried adding in both levels of the <tr><td> before and it only adds more space and everything remains the same.  You also added the table data twice.  which I don't think was your intention. I'm still facing the same issue which is driving me crazy. Any other ideas?